# How to create a B2C shop with request to quote and B2B that shows the prices (role based pricing and button changes)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am setting up a woocommerce store, using the flatsome theme. For non-registered users, almost the entire product catalogue should be visible and they should be able to request a quote. Customers who have their own login, prices should be visible and the the customer can order.

I am running into one problem:
1. How do I make the button, add to cart, visible for "logged in" users, and the "request a quote" button only visible for non-logged in users? And how to differentiate the url's behind the "shopping cart" button so they  have the right page in front of them?

I am using the "request a quote" plugin, and I am using the role editor to ensure registration. Customers are not able to register themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in WordPress you can use to check if a user is logged in or not:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Your add to cart button
} else {
    // Your request a quote button
}
```

This is all I can do at the moment because I don't see any code in your question. Hope this helps.